# How to build dynamic routes with internationalized routes (i18n) using Next.js without getStaticPaths?

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, dynamic-routing

I’m trying to find a solution for building simple dummy dynamic routes to have something like: /order/{productid}.

Next allows us to take different strategies, but in order to achieve what I need it seems, I saw two possibilities:

1. **Static paths generation**:
   Since I have around 1400+ products, static generation for it would only make sense if I could use ISR, so I could fetch only a few offers and leave the rest to be incrementally generated using ISR. Unfortunately my usecase doesn't allow me to use ISR since I'm in Europe and the lambdas created by this feature are in the US, and this is a restriction for me.
2. **basic dynamic routing** :
   I tried to run dummy examples with dynamic routes, but when doing this with i18n setup, it falls into an infinite loop.
   I tried really hard to research about it and I found nothing useful.

**What have I tried?**
I took this example https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes and added i18n to the docs example so that I could showcase the issue.

You can find it here: https://github.com/sergioviniciuss/next-dynamic-routing-i18n

Please, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: The app you linked runs fine, including the dynamic route. What issue are you seeing exactly?

Comment: it doesn't.. if you navigate to one of the dynamically generated pages, you'll fall into an infinite loop. I managed to solve it, and the issue seems to be because in the next.config file, when I pass localhost, I was passing the port as well (it's part of the domain in the end, but it's the cause of the issue. I just removed the port and it worked like a charm. I requested them to update the docs and give more clarity on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was actually because I was passing the port in my i18n domains config.
For localhost, I was passing also the port, and that was causing an infinite loop:

```json
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'localhost:3000',
        locales: [
          "de-DE",
          "de-AT",
          "en-US",
          "en-IE",
          "en-GB",
          "nl-NL",
          "es-ES",
          "fr-FR",
        ],
        defaultLocale: process.env.APP_LOCALE || "en-US",
        http: true,
      },
    ],
```

So instead of `domain: 'localhost:3000',` it should be `domain: 'localhost',`

And it works like a charm.

Comment: I love you. I was using a domain alias defined in etc/hosts, but my mistake was putting the port on the next.config.js too.

Thanks so much!

Comment: haha no worries @DiegoCastañoChillarón ! it's something next.js could improve in the docs (maybe they already did), but it's definitely not obvious to figure out.